# What is the "wallet export format"?

Tags: development, address, encoding, address-format, ecdsa

The "wallet export format" is mentioned at the Wiki page for [Mini private key format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mini_private_key_format), but it doesn't seem to be explained on the Wiki. How does one convert the export format to and from corresponding keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was explained [on the forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=57396.0), it is a base58 encoded private key with added 0x80 byte at the front and 4 checksum bytes at the end.

More detailed explanation is not available [on the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format), as well as in [a new testing suite](http://gobittest.appspot.com/PrivateKey).